# Why will "the adress of bool will always evaluate as true" here?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to understand how function pointers work. This is represents the setup:

```
bool f1(int x){
    if(condition){return true;}
    else return false;
}

bool f2(int x, bool (*func)(int)){
    if (func(x)){return true;}
    else return false;
}

void f3(int x, bool (*func)(int, bool)){
    if (func(x, f1)) {return "Whatever";}
    else return "Nevermind";

int main(){
    f3(x, f2);
}
```

This gives me:
In function 'void f3()':
"warning: the adress of bool 'f1(int)' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]
In function 'int main()':
error: invalid conversion from 'bool (*)(int,bool (*)(int))' to 'bool (*)(int, bool)'

How much am I messing up?

Comment: You are passing an address of function `f1`, you probably wanted to call it.

Comment: Instead of `if(condition) return true; else return false;` you should get in the habit of `return condition;`. It's much simpler and shorter and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void f3(int x, bool (*func)(int, bool)){
>                                  ^^^^
> ```

Your second parameter of `f3` is a pointer to a function with a second argument of `bool`.

`f2` is the type of function you want to pass to `f3`, and call from `f3`, but `f2`'s second parameter has type `bool (*)(int)`.

So `f3` should be declared accordingly:

```
void f3(int x, bool (*func)(int, bool (*)(int)))
```

Note: this can be made far more readable by using `typedef` appropriately:

```
typedef bool f1_t(int);
typedef bool f2_t(int, f1_t*);

bool f1(int x) { ... }
bool f2(int x, f1_t* func) { ... }
void f3(int x, f2_t* func) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

A function pointer will always be non-null if you generate it directly from the address of a function, and only a null pointer will evaluate to `false`.

The second parameter of `func` needs to be a `bool`, but you're passing it the name of a function. The function is automatically converted to a pointer to the function, which is then automatically converted to `bool` using the rule above.